# ''No pictures/videos' in my Shotwell

Tags: shotwell

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 and I have a lot of pictures on my system, but when I open the main Shotwell window, it doesn't show any pictures at all!

[image: What it shows on main window!]

Answer (score 1):

You have to **import** media into Shotwell for it to show up in your library. This option should be in the main Shotwell menu.

There is also a Shotwell viewer that you can use by right clicking and selecting **Open with...**